# Ошибка при использовании многострочного текста

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Как исправлять эту ошибку?

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');

var phone = '3434343435345';
var text = 'text';

cmd.run([
  '
  curl --location --request POST "sms-gat.uz/api/message/sms/send" --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjQxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbm90aWZ5LmVza2l6LnV6L2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTY2NDYzMzI2LCJleHAiOjE1NjkwNTUzMjYsIm5iZiI6MTU2NjQ2MzMyNiwianRpIjoiSlYxVW1MMFJvVEY5SEpFeSJ9.dPaqcPV3ijgyN2B2aWFoWJwHJ1QJhQ3gEHWLH59sT50" --form "mobile_phone={phone}" --form "message={text}"
  '
]);
```

Comment: Учить синтаксис и пользоваться хорошими редакторами кода которые подсвечивают ошибки

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужен многострочный текст, то заключайте его в ``` `` ```.

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');

var phone = '3434343435345';
var text = 'text';

cmd.run([
    `
    curl --location --request POST "sms-gat.uz/api/message/sms/send" --header "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjQxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbm90aWZ5LmVza2l6LnV6L2FwaS9hdXRoL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTY2NDYzMzI2LCJleHAiOjE1NjkwNTUzMjYsIm5iZiI6MTU2NjQ2MzMyNiwianRpIjoiSlYxVW1MMFJvVEY5SEpFeSJ9.dPaqcPV3ijgyN2B2aWFoWJwHJ1QJhQ3gEHWLH59sT50" --form "mobile_phone={phone}" --form "message={text}"
    `
]);
```

Comment: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Re
ceived type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11)
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:411:3)
    at spawn (child_process.js:545:16)
    at Object.execFile (child_process.js:221:15)
    at exec (child_process.js:152:18)
    at Object.runCommand [as run] (C:\Users\H4623R\Desktop\smss\node_modules\nod
e-cmd\cmd.js:10:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\H4623R\Desktop\smss\sms.js:4:5)